# White fuzzy weed ID

Tags: identification, weeds

What is this white fuzzy weed? They are covering my land, and surrounding, in middle New Mexico. It's an arid, desert climate, with lots of rain recently. The plant varies from 2 to 4 inches across. The white fuzz isn't attached to the plant, and is very clinging [image]

Comment: I don't know, but maybe the white stuff isn't part of the plant. Maybe it's some kind of spider, mite or caterpillar that made this. If so, someone might recognize the plant if you add a photo without fuzz.

Comment: I haven't seen one without fuzz, and it's only these little plants that have it

Comment: It was in the back of my brain, having went to school in NM.  Then I thought of it soaking in the tub!  It's in Utah too, where I live, but not near me.  It's not a weed really (unless you don't want it where it's groiwing), but a native plant.  It's perennial, though not that long-lived, and responds to rains and favorable conditions. The hairs may be to protect from being eaten, to protect from the harsh sun, or possibly some other reason - we really don't know.  I think they are pretty cool plants.

Comment: @Eric We certainly got a lot of rain in NM this year. Wiped out the 4 year drought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *Dasyochloa pulchella*, fluffgrass. http://extension.usu.edu/rangeplants/htm/fluffgrass

Comment: I never thought I'd get an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this kind of "hair" on the Old Man Cactus, it looks like a succulent but it's a cactus although I forgot the name of it.